# ReactJS - Lightbox component Issue

Tags: reactjs

I installed a react-lightbox-component dependence and it isn't showing the maximized zoom image. Does anybody know if I misstep something?

Here is the component official page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lightbox-component

I ran `yarn add react-lightbox-component` and I made this component by importing the react-component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

const LightBoxTest = () => (

  <div>
   <Lightbox images={ [
      {
        src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Ropy_pahoehoe.jpg',
        title: 'Ropy pahoehoe',
        description: 'By Tari Noelani Mattox. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Pyroclastic_flows_at_Mayon_Volcano.jpg',
        title: 'Pyroclastic flows at Mayon Volcano',
        description: 'By C.G. Newhall. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Okataina.jpg',
        title: 'Okataina',
        description: 'By Richard Waitt. Licensed under Public Domain via Commons'
      }
    ] }/>
  </div>
);


export default LightBoxTest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the CSS of the `react-lighthouse-component` as well.

```
import "react-lightbox-component/build/css/index.css";
```